# SQL update statement setting the same value back

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am looking at a stored procedure in SQL and have come across a curious update statement. It goes like this.

```
UPDATE dbo.Table_name
SET [Column_name] = [Column_name]
WHERE [Column_ID] = '2564-5131'
```

I fail to understand the significance of this update statement.

I new to SQL so might be missing a point here.

**EDIT:**

I checked the table defination for triggers as mentioned in some comments below but didn't find anything.

The table defination only contains these

- Primary key clustered
- Foreign key that references another table
- Constraint for a column with TinyInt type to check the value remains within bounds
- And a non-clustered index on one column

Comment: Maybe there's a trigger defined that the update triggers. But I agree, it looks weird.

Comment: The syntax looks like SQL Server, so I've tagged it appropriately.

Comment: Is it really a column_Id or it is also a column name from dbo.table_name ?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite It is just the column_Id where column_Id takes a GUID.

Comment: Does the non-clustered index cover [Column_Name]?  If so, then it might be a lazy way to trigger the table to be re-indexed.  Of course, it's always possible you uncovered a bug, or somebody's debug code they forgot to remove.

Comment: No. The non-clustered index is on some other column. Also this [Column_name] is of type DATETIME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to figure out what that update does and thought would document it here.

It turns out that this exact update statement is present in multiple stored procedures and this non-functional update acts as an explicit lock between these stored procedures. It causes all the stored procs to be serialized.

I guess this is not an optimal design for maximum throughput. Apparently this was done to avoid many deadlocks that were observed if the stored procs were not serialized.

Answer (score 0):

This does nothing by itself, but there is probably a trigger defined on the table for updates that will do something.  Check the table definition for triggers.

Comment: I checked the table defination and no triggers are defined on this table.